# Recursive invocations / fork invocations in AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm using AWS Lambda in NodeJS. With this lambda, I want to **add a book** in DynamboDB. It works fine.

Now, I want to do it for a **list of books**. I have some ideas but I don't know if it's possible in AWS lambda.

### idea 1 : fork several lamba

I'm wondering if it's possible to have a "master" Lambda that have a list of books to add, and **foreach books** invoke a lambda function "insert book". The maximum timeout is 5 minutes so it's possible to make an asynchronous invocation from the "master" lambda in order to not wait for all forked lambda process ?

### idea 2 : recursive invocations

Create a generic lambda that process the first book of a list of books passed as input. At the end of the process, remove the book from the list (if OK) and invoke the same lambda with the updated List.

Note : the first invocation need to get the list of books.

Many thanks for your help !

Romain.

Comment: You haven't provided a lot of details but from the description I think what I would do is have a Lambda function that can add a book record to your DynamoDB table and then hook that function up to an SNS topic and publish an event to that topic for each book you want to add.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have processing you didn't mention that takes so long that you can't add multiple books in one invocation of the lambda function.

You can both fanout and recursively invoke your lambda function.
There are benefits and drawbacks to both.

If you fanout to too many, too often, your dynamodb writes could spike above provisioned write capacity.

If you recursively call your function you will not be able to return a value to the caller. (Assuming that the whole chain of call takes more than five minutes.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try to recursively call my Lambda function.!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your issue is that you don't own the context of the computation. Using a 'master' lambda would definitely solve this. There are a few different solutions for how to do do the invocations.

1. For every book in the list publish to a sns topic that the 'child'-lambda subscribes to. Here is a link for how to make a lambda subscribe to a sns topic http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-lambda.html. To publish to the sns topic you simple use the AWS SNS SDK for the language of the master lambda.
2. Invoke the lambdas with the AWS Lambda SDK within the 'master' lambda. An example node script of how to do this is shown below:

```js
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const lambda = Promise.promisifyAll(new AWS.Lambda({ apiVersion: '2015-03-31' }));

const listOfBook = ['Book One', 'Book Two', 'Book Three'];

const bookEntryStats = {
    successFullBookEntries: [],
    failedBookEntries: []
};

Promise.map(listOfBooks, function (book) {

    return lambda.invokeAsync({FunctionName: 'ChildLambdaFunctionName', Payload: new Buffer(book)}).then(function () {
        bookEntryStats.successFullBookEntries.push(book);
    }).catch(function () {
        bookEntryStats.failedBookEntries.push(book);
    });
}, {concurrency: 20})
    .then(function () {
        console.log(bookEntryStats);
    });
```

If using the sns approach you need to consider that it is hard to control how many concurrent lambdas you will execute as you 'lose' the context of the execution the moment you publish to the sns topic. Since there is a hard limit on how many concurrent lambdas you can execute at the same time you will easily cause throttling if the list of books is long.

The second approach might not be as elegant, but the 'concurrency' parameter of the Promise.map function lets you control how many lambda functions that are executed at any given point.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This API is deprecated. They recommend you use Invoke API,  with InvocationType set to Event  rather than the default of RequestResponse. 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html

Answer (score 0):

I've recently started to fiddle around with AWS Lambda and ran into your problem. I want to initiate, through a web service call (API Gateway), a large batch (50000) of jobs. The work needs to be completed as soon as possible, meaning, overhead time plus the amount of time one job takes to complete.

I got this idea:

A. Two functions.

- Lambda function named **worker**, carries out work using payload data.
- Lambda function named **dispatcher**, calls itself or **worker**.

B. One payload initially.

Call web service with a list of objects as payload, each object contains the data that the worker need to complete the work. Web service hands the payload over to the first **dispatcher**.

C. **Dispatcher** does not return anything, rather you use a pollable web service call to check status of all jobs.

So, example.

You call the web service with 50000 objects in the JSON payload, web service calls first **dispatcher**. Of course, the **dispatcher** can't iterate through all of those sequencially without hitting max execution time (of AWS Lambda), so it splits the incoming list to 10 new lists. This means that next **dispatchers** are now called 10 times, each with a list of objects with the size of 5000.

The **dispatcher** continues doing this until they are so many holding such small lists of objects that you trust it can start iterating the list, calling **worker** function for each one of them.

So if the **dispatcher** is configured to only carry out jobs when the incoming list is 10 objects or less, in this example, 5000 **dispatchers** will each iterate it's list with 10 objects, calling the **worker** lambda function carrying out the job.

That's my idea, which I am working with right now. I'm not sure if I will hit any AWS restrictions that I'm not aware of. I know the set limitations such as payload size when calling a Lambda function, max execution time etc.

In theory, this can scale indefinitely.